# How to terminate Oracle procedures which is running

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I created an oracle procedure. When i execute it from sqldevoloper in some case i think it is going into an infinite loop. It keeps on generating the log files. How can i terminate this running procedure? 
I stopped the oracle service through services.msc . When i start it again , log files are getting generated. I think still that procedure is running. 
How can i terminate those procedures.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill a running SELECT statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545560/how-to-kill-a-running-select-statement)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Identify your session (hung) from v$session using

```
select sid, serial#, status from v$session where USERNAME='NAME';
```

And then kill it using

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'SID,#SERIAL';
```

Comment: i don't have the db admin right. I have access to taskmanager and services. so is there any way i can kill it from taskmanager or services.

Comment: ask a DBA (or someone with rights on db) to stop the session, killing just the client process is not always a good idea.

Comment: @vikiiii to check this query..i created an infinte loop procedure in my local db in which i have admin rights. procedure is running and i executed this query with my username. it is not returning any results.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION
```

But you have to retrieve session id and have rights.