# how to come out of an infinite loop without closing the prompt in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone please tell how to come out of an infinite loop in pl/sql without closing the prompt? I had missed exit when unknowingly so the program went into an infinite loop and finally i closed the prompt and lost the program.

Comment: No chance for an answer without code example.

Comment: @Toru - disagree.  This is a general programming question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill a running SELECT statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545560/how-to-kill-a-running-select-statement)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you're already in this situation and you have a looping statement running that is consuming resources, and you no longer have access to the session from your client; you need to kill the session, from an account that has the privileges to do that:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

Or you can [kill it from SQL Developer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/monitoring.htm#CEGIFCFA).

You can find information about identifying the session [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/manproc008.htm), or a summary [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions.php).

As always, be sure you're killing the right thing to avoid damaging something else by accident.

---

Before closing the 'prompt' you could probably have used `control-c` to interrupt the statement and regain control.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're in a loop the only way out is to kill the client program (the database will eventually notice that the session is orphaned and kill it) or ask [a DBA to kill the session for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17011037/146325). Either way you lose the program.

The only way to come cleanly out of an infinite loop is not to code an infinite loop in the first place.

How to do that?  Well, firstly, we can check our code before we run it.  We can reinforce this technique by using a decent editor which supports code snippets.  That at least offers the possibility of templates for the various forms of LOOP which include the clauses for the EXIT condition.  Snippets are great as [a poka-yoke](http://www.poka-yoke.org.uk/) technique.

Secondly we can run unit tests with *controlled data*.  This won't prevent us coding an infinite loop but it will allow us to catch one before putting our code into production.

Thirdy, use monitoring.  We can instrument our PL/SQL using DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_SESSION_LONGOPS().  That offers a window which allows us to see how often a loop is being called.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_appinf.htm#i996999).

Comment: I'd put using a debugger on that list also.