# "Zombie Requests" CFQUERY tags get stuck and are unkillable

Tags: coldfusion

- Coldfusion 2016
- Microsoft Server 2012
- Oracle 12
- ODBC connection

I turned on profiling and monitoring and now I can see that there are requests that are stuck and cannot be terminated by the CF monitor; Some are over 200k seconds.

I know I can increase the number of simultaneous requests  but I want to solve the underlying problem. As I read the stack traces of these “zombie requests” they are getting stuck on  and some are in  but some are not. I ran the query in my oracle client and they resolve instantly.

Is there a way to terminate these requests or prevent this from happening at all?

**EDIT:** The server monitor does not treat these requests as slow or hung, the alerts are not triggering for any of these. Honestly, they should have be going off constantly considering how many of these there are.

Also, the execution time is a mere .003 seconds so what happened? Why doesn't ColdFusion know this?

An example of a "zombie" [image: "zombie"]
The active query that is stuck [image: stuck]

Comment: This might help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545560/how-to-kill-a-running-select-statement

Comment: I'll ask the DBA if there are any errors there or unresolved sessions.

Comment: Just checking: are you using ODBC or JDBC?

Comment: Try using a NOLOCK on the table. I could be that your query is hanging as it waits for something else to finish. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210171/effect-of-nolock-hint-in-select-statements

Comment: @LeonidAlzhin Yes its an ODBC connection

Comment: @JamesAMohler, are you sure Oracle supports Nolock?

Comment: I see that it doesn't: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149350/why-oracle-doesnt-have-nolock

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation with a different database engine - redbrick, which runs on a unix server.  We solved it as follows.

We set up a cron job on the database server to run every 5 minutes.  This job uses a combination of unix and awk commands.

This job runs a query against the system table that looks for queries that have been running for more than 120 seconds, where the database account is the one used by ColdFusion.  Records are outputted to a file.  Something like this:

```
print "alter system cancel user command userName process "  $1 ";"
```

$1 comes from the query and is the process Id we want to stop.

Then we run the file, which executes all those alter system commands.

With a different database engine, and possible different OS for the database server, the details would be different, but the approach should work.

**Edit Starts Here**

To prevent recurrence, look at the pages that call the ones with the long running queries.  If impatient users are able to repeatedly click something because nothing is happening, do something about that.  You can use javascript to make the link/button go away.  Alternatively, you can go to an intermediate page with a display for the user and something that carries them through to the real page.

Comment: Yes that is a possibility as well, I have seen the same request from the same IP is a short period of time.